# Why the predicted MSE loss is hundreds of times the training loss？

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

```
def loss_train(y_true, y_pred):
    square_diff = tf.math.squared_difference(y_true, y_pred)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(square_diff)
    return loss
```

I use tensorflow_2.5, training a regression model, here is my loss function.
when the loss  reduced to 0.06， the predicted loss is about 18.0 tested on the same trainset.

```
# the predicted loss function
def loss_predict(y_true, y_pred):
    s_d = (y_true - y_pred)*(y_true - y_pred)
    loss = np.mean(s_d)
    return loss
```

Why is the predicted loss so big?

```
def predict_train_data(path_weights,path_tfrec):

model = model_yoo()
model.load_weights(path_weights)
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path_tfrec)
parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(parse_tfrecord_fn)

loss_pre = 0
count = 0.00000001
for features in parsed_dataset.take(128):
    gt = features["offset"]
    image0 = features["image0"]
    image1 = features["image1"]

    image = tf.concat([image0, image1], 2) 
    image = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) - 127.5)/ 127.5
    image = tf.expand_dims(image,0)

    res = model.predict(image)[0]
    pre = res*32
 
    loss_pre += loss_predict(pre,gt)
    count += 1

print("predict loss: ",loss_pre / count)

return
```

Comment: I do not think these two losses are computing the same quantities, due to broadcasting and matrix multiplication.

Comment: @jituan What's the dtype and shape of `y_true/y_pred`?

Comment: @skywall Thanks  your answer！ it's (None,8)/(None,8) and float32/float32 when i was training.     (8,)/(8,) and float32/<dtype: 'float32'>  when predict

Comment: The doc for tf.keras.losses says that the loss function call should return 'Loss values with the shape [batch_size, d0, .. dN-1]'. I think your loss_train function is returning a scalar. I'm not completely sure how this affects things but you could try making it conform with the doc. (i.e. don't tf.reduce_mean over the first axis). https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss